# How to simulate key press event onload

Tags: javascript, jquery, keypress, simulate

How can I simulate a `keyPress` event to open the print menu on Chrome with JavaScript or jQuery?

The keys are `Ctrl` + `P`

I tried this code in JavaScript but it doesn't work.

```
function imprimer() {
    robot.keyPress(17);
    robot.keyPress(80);
}
window.onload = imprimer();
```

Comment: is `robot.keyPress` part of some library, or is it something you made up in the hope that javascript would understand "what you mean"

Comment: try to read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/596481/simulate-javascript-key-events

Comment: thank for your answer, but the window.print() function is better to do that :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you want use window.print() function..